# How to replace a letter in string globally without replacing the instance of the letter in word

Tags: javascript, string, regexp-replace

For example given a string **:**

```
let str = 'a man at a house';
```

using RegEx constructor, How can get the string as `the man at the house` instead of `the mthen thet the house` when replacing `a` with `the` ?

Comment: It sounds like you want to replace a whole word, not the letter. So use the `\b` word boundary in the regexp.

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research - [search SO for answers](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+regex+word+not+letter+site%3Astackoverflow.com).  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Answer (score 0):

As you want to replace a whole word (`a`) instead of a letter. You can simply do it by using [`string.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method.

I am using `\b` here in the RegEx as it matches at word boundaries (without actually matching any characters).

```js
// Input string
let str = 'a man at a house';

// As 'a' should be a whole word. Then it will always contains a white space either before, after or both the sides. Then we can do something like this to replace.
str = str.replace(/\b(a)\b/g, 'the');

// Output
console.log(str);
```